# java import packages from the command line

Tags: java, compiler-errors, jasper-reports

On Linux, from the command line, I am running an ant script to build a java project. 
I use JasperReports in the exercise. But my question is a general one.
I get a compile error:
package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;

What I have tried is to set the CLASSPATH=path to the JasperReport jar file
export CLASSPATH=path to the jar file
and then run the ant script, same error.

What is it that I am not doing?

Comment: may be some of the dependent jars are missing for the jasper jar files? Readme file might help if there are any., Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must manage the classpath for an ant build *inside the ant build*. See the `<javac/>` element documentation, and correctly specify the classpath.